# Is there a way to see which rows a postgres query has scanned or modified for any statement?

Tags: postgresql

I'm working on a tool for postgres and trying to find a way to see what rows a given query scans or touches. Ideally, I'd like to get back a list of tables and the primary keys of the tables that the query scanned or touched. Worst case, at least just the number of rows per table the query touched. I tried `pg_audit` but that didn't give me number of rows touched. Also tried triggers but postgres explicitly states that triggers can't be invoked from `select` statements, only `insert`, `delete` and `updates`.

Would really appreciate any help!

Comment: `explain analyze` will tell you the number of rows per table the query touched.